# On gremlin console, why predicate 'eq' returning false inside 'is' while direct comparison returns true?

Tags: groovy, gremlin

On gremlin version 3.4.0 with step `is`, the predicates are not working as expected.

if I do the following it is returning me true

```
gremlin>3.is(3)
==>true
gremlin>[3].getAt(0).is(3)
==>true
```

While the same comparisons with using predicates are not working and returns false

```
gremlin>3.is(eq(3))
==>false
gremlin>[3].getAt(0).is(eq(3))
==>false
```

Precisely I want to check the length of the node property value and validate based on a max length.

```
gremlin>g.V(0).values('name').next().length().is(lte(20))
==>false
```

The above code always return false is the name is equal to `test_name` (with length 9). While if I do direct comparison (like shown below) it returns true

```
gremlin>g.V(0).values('name').next().length().is(9)
==>true
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing Groovy and Gremlin. When you do this:

```
gremlin>3.is(3)
==>true
gremlin>[3].getAt(0).is(3)
==>true
```

you are not using Gremlin and that is therefore not the `is()` step. In that case you are doing a [reference equality check](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_identity_operator) using Groovy's `is()` method. That further explains your results as you go further down in your question as in:

```
gremlin>g.V(0).values('name').next().length().is(lte(20))
==>false
```

because as soon as you do `next()` you are no longer doing Gremlin. Nothing following that represent Gremlin steps, it's just Groovy code. You are calling the `String.length()` method and then the Groovy `is()` operator and comparing the `int` returned from `length()` to `lte(20)` which is an instance of `P` thus:

```
gremlin> "xyz".length().is(lte(20))
==>false
```

If you want to use Gremlin to check the length of a string then I'm not sure that there is a way to do so outside of using a lambda:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().values('name').filter{it.get().length()<=4}
==>lop
==>josh
```

Comment: Thank you, I very much appreciate for the clarification. It worked for me.